# Treemap Constructor

Tags: java, treemap

Is the way I am trying to setup my treemap constructor correct?

```
import java.util.TreeMap ;

public class Table<K extends Comparable<K>, T> { //K = Key, T = Item

    TreeMap<K, T> tm;

    public Table<K, T> () {
        tm = new TreeMap<K, T>();
    }


    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return tm.isEmpty();
    }

    public int size() {
        return tm.size();
    }

    public void tableInsert(K key, T item) throws TableException {
        tm.put(key, item);
    }

    public boolean tableDelete(K key) {
        if (tm.containsKey(key)) {
            tm.remove(key);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public T tableRetreive(K key) {
        return tm.get(key);
    } //return null if not found

    public void printTable() {
        TreeMap<K, T> tmclone = (TreeMap<K, T>) tm.clone();
        while (!tmclone.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(tmclone.pollFirstEntry());
        }


    } //print in search key order
}
```

I have another class that will create `students`, and with the `put` method will insert into a new map tree.. but the compiler says it was expecting a different character. Also, is the proper way to call the constructor is to input `TreeMap blah<K,T> = new TreeMap` correct?

Comment: If you get a build error, put it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code here:

```
public Table<K, T> () {
    tm = new TreeMap<K, T>();
}
```

needs to change to this:

```
public Table() {
    tm = new TreeMap<K, T>();
}
```

Otherwise all good.

Comment: When i call "Table sTable = new Table();" from my main method it doesn't compile with that constructor. Is it expecting parameters for K and T?

Comment: When you instantiate a `Table`, you will need type parameters for the keys and values, or you will get a compiler warning.  Depending on the types you need for the `Table`, something like `Table<String, String> sTable = new Table<String, String>();` should work.

Comment: Ah, you are correct sir! Okay, So I would need to do Table<Integer, Student> since I need the a number to match to a student object..

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if the initialization in the constructor is functional(?), yes. You could also make an initializer above the constructor like this:

```
public class Table <K extends Comparable<K>, T> { //K = Key, T = Item
     TreeMap<K,T> tm;

     { //Initializer
          tm = new TreeMap<K,T>();
     }

     public Table<K,T>() {
         //Your constructor here
     }

     //Other methods...
}
```

As far as the second part of your question, there is far too little based on your description to diagnose the issue without seeing some more code and getting more details.

Comment: Why do you put braces around `tm` initialization?

Comment: This is an initializer:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: What's the difference when it's not an "initializer" i.e. when there are no braces around it?

Comment: Initializers are just fields in a class to initialize reference types. The above documentation has good explanations on the nuances